# Why is Google+ post's preview not recognizing UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, google-plus

When I try to share an article page on Google+ by putting its URL into the post, a preview is displayed with article's title, description and image. The problem is that the showed text is not UTF-8 and does not mean anything - Here is an example of what the post preview displays as an article's decription:

```
zveÅ™ejnÃ vÃ½sledky vyÅ¡etÅ™ovÃ¡nÃ afÃ©ry
```

Try it for yourself - visit this page and try to share it on Google+: https://roklen24.cz/a/pzbmw/kdo-opravdu-stoji-za-burzovnimi-krachy-vinte-pocitace

Facebook sharing works fine, only Google+ is having this issue. It is not just one or two characters problem, each character with punctuation is behaving like that - it's mostly replaced by a character `A` with different punctuiation - here is an example:

ORIGINAL string: `zveřejněné výsledky vyšetřování aféry`

DISPLAYED string: `zveÅ™ejnÃ vÃ½sledky vyÅ¡etÅ™ovÃ¡nÃ afÃ©ry`

Could You tell what might be causing this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue was a bug on the Google side because it used to be working before.
I got the same problem as you said too but it seems to be fixed just few minutes ago.

[Now??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoZzC.png)
[10Hr before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRZyQ.png)